# performance tuning weblogic

Tags: java, performance, weblogic

We have a very unstable system which runs on Weblogic 10.3 portal and we would like somehow

for a while to keep it up by limiting the number of users it can handle to 100 or 200.

Is there a way where we can set this ?

self-tuning-thread-pool-size-max  is still available in 10.3 ?

(don't find any documentation related to 10.3 regarding this)

Thank you very much for help !

Comment: The person who flagged this for movement to SuperUser needs to explain why SuperUser is a better place to answer this question.

Comment: are you getting any exception when modifying the domain to incorporate the `self-tuning-thread-pool-size-max` value? I don't think this parameter has gone away, but again, a work manager for your application sounds like the best approach.

Comment: Yes a work manager will be more appropiate...read about it and configured 

   <max-threads-constraint>
      <name>PPW_Max</name> 
      <count>100</count> 
   </max-threads-constraint>

   <min-threads-constraint>
      <name>PPW_Min</name> 
       <count>50</count> 
   </min-threads-constraint>

    <capacity> 
      <name>PPW_CapacityConstraint</name> 
            <count>100</count> 
         </capacity> 

 
     <work-manager>
      <name>PPWWorkManager</name> 
     </work-manager>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably describe the behavior you want.  A work manager with a max threads constraint of 100 will not limit your application to 100 users, but it will limit it to servicing 100 concurrent requests at the same time.
http://blogs.oracle.com/jamesbayer/entry/weblogic_server_work_manager_demo

If you want to limit it to 100 users, then consider setting the max in-memory sessions if you're using sessions.  You can set this in the weblogic.xml deployment descriptor or in the wls console in the configuration->general section of your deployment.
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13712/weblogic_xml.htm#i1071981

Comment: Thank you....i did also some research and came to the same conclusions.Meanwhile somebody recommended to reduce Maximum Open Sockets but i doubt that would be good.